# How to add custom properties to Paperjs objects?

Tags: paperjs

I found some discussions about doing this using the `inject` method, like this one https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/paperjs/16ToDJquig8

But I cannot find this method in the official doc.  So what is the officially recommended way to add custom properties to Paperjs objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to add properties to an Item, you can use `Item.data`.

From [paper.js documentation](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#data):

> Item.data: A plain javascript object which can be used to store arbitrary data on the item.

Example:

```
var path = new Path();
path.data.remember = 'milk';
```